# Help with PHP loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Suppose I have a multi-dimensional array of the form:

```
array
(
    array('Set_ID' => 1, 'Item_ID' => 17, 'Item_Name' = 'Whatever'),
    array('Set_ID' => 1, 'Item_ID' => 18, 'Item_Name' = 'Blah'),
    array('Set_ID' => 2, 'Item_ID' => 19, 'Item_Name' = 'Yo')
)
```

The array has more sub-arrays, but that's the basic form-- Items in Sets.

How can I loop through this array so that I can echo the number of items in each set along with the all the items like so:

```
Set 1 has 2 Items: 17: Whatever and 18: Blah
Set 2 has 1 Items: 19: Yo
```

I'm aware that this could be done with two loops-- one to build an array, and another to loop through that array.  However, I'd like to do this all with only one loop.

In your answer, you should assume that there are two display functions

```
display_set($id, $count) //echo's "Set $id has $count Items"
display_item($id, $name) //echo's "$id: $name"
```

UPDATE: Forgot to mention that the data is sorted by Set_ID because its from SQL

Comment: @DeathMagus: I was just about to say that after reading the last bit...

Comment: Eh, it's not homework.  It's a looping structure i've never run into.  I'm going to update the post with my own attempt at this, I just want to see if I can get it right

Comment: Why a single loop? In order to get the numerical data for the count, or indeed the contents of the list a full traversal is needed.  Only after a single parse can any data be output, without a second loop outputting the data is tricky.  Sure you can use commands to generate the data without seeing more than a single loop statement, but most likely there would be more under-the-hood.

Comment: A single loop is more elegant and efficient than building an array then doing another loop.  I'm going to post my attempt in a second

Comment: It may be an interesting challenge, but fixating on the 'single loop holy grail' will not produce better code. Contorting what should be a simple algorithm (aggregate then display) to satisfy this will make the code less readable (which to me is less elegant). As for efficiency: you know the one about the "root of all evil," right? If performance really *is* critical here, you might get more mileage by aggregating in the database (mysql group_concat).

Comment: @grossvogel: Quite right, efficiency and elegance are not always the fondest of friends.

Comment: I went into this thinking there was a simple structure to solve it all.. Now I just feel like a perfectionist.. it apparently is not a simple problem like i thought it would be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, all the examples below rely on an ordered set, the OP states it is ordered initially, but if needed a sort function could be:

```
// Sort set in to order
usort($displaySet,
      create_function('$a,$b',
                      'return ($a['Set_ID'] == $b['Set_ID']
                               ? ($a['Set_ID'] == $b['Item_ID']
                                  ? 0
                                  : ($a['Item_ID'] < $b['Item_ID']
                                     ? -1
                                     : 1))
                               : ($a['Set_ID'] < $b['Set_ID'] ? -1 : 1));'));
```

Straight example using a single loop:

```
// Initialise for the first set
$cSetID = $displaySet[0]['Set_ID'];
$cSetEntries = array();

foreach ($displaySet as $cItem) {
  if ($cSetID !== $cItem['Set_ID']) {
    // A new set has been seen, display old set
    display_set($cSetID, count($cSetEntries));
    echo ": " . implode(" and ", $cSetEntries) . "\n";
    $cSetID = $cItem['Set_ID'];
    $cSetEntries = array();
  }

  // Store item display for later
  ob_start();
  display_item($cItem['Item_ID'], $cItem['Item_Name');
  $cSetEntries[] = ob_get_clean();
}

// Perform last set display
display_set($cSetID, count($cSetEntries));
echo ": " . implode(" and ", $cSetEntries) . "\n";
```

Using a recursive function it could be something like this:

```
// Define recursive display function
function displayItemList($itemList) {
  if (!empty($itemList)) {
    $cItem = array_shift($itemList);
    display_item($cItem['Item_ID'], $cItem['Item_Name');

    if (!empty($itemList)) {
      echo " and ";
    }
  }

  displayItemList($itemList);
}

// Initialise for the first set
$cSetID = $displaySet[0]['Set_ID'];
$cSetEntries = array();

foreach ($displaySet as $cItem) {
  if ($cSetID !== $cItem['Set_ID']) {
    // A new set has been seen, display old set
    display_set($cSetID, count($cSetEntries));
    echo ": ";
    displayItemList($cSetEntries);
    echo "\n";
    $cSetID = $cItem['Set_ID'];
    $cSetEntries = array();
  }

  // Store item for later
  $cSetEntries[] = $cItem;
}

// Perform last set display
display_set($cSetID, count($cSetEntries));
echo ": ";
displayItemList($cSetEntries);
echo "\n";
```

Amusingly, it can be one single recursive function:

```
function displaySetList($setList, $itemList = NULL) {
  // First call, start process
  if ($itemList === NULL) {
    $itemList = array(array_shift($setList));
    displaySetList($setList, $itemList);

    return;
  }

  // Check for display item list mode
  if ($setList === false) {
    // Output first entry in the list
    $cItem = array_shift($itemList);
    display_item($cItem['Item_ID'], $cItem['Item_Name']);

    if (!empty($itemList)) {
      // Output the next
      echo " and ";
      displaySetList(false, $itemList);
    } else {
      echo "\n";
    }

    return;
  }

  if (empty($setList) || $setList[0]['Set_ID'] != $itemList[0]['Set_ID']) {
    // New Set detected, output set
    display_set($itemList[0]['Set_ID'], count($itemList));
    echo ": ";
    displaySetList(false, $itemList);
    $itemList = array();
  }

  // Add next item and carry on
  $itemList[] = array_shift($setList);
  displaySetList($setList, $itemList);
}

// Execute the function
displaySetList($displaySet);
```

Note that the recursive example here is grossly inefficient, a double loop is by far the quickest.

Comment: so the problem is such that controlling the echo's through ob_ functions is the only way?

Comment: No it is not the only way, but as you stated that `display_item()` echoes immediately, it is convenient to store up the results.  Note there is still an implicit inner-loop within `implode()`.  If that were removed and the output buffering was removed, then a new inner loop would be needed as in Anon.'s solution.  The only other way would be a recursive function to avoid the loop.

Comment: @babonk: Added a version with no loops at all for you.  Just for fun, efficiency is not it's strong point.

Comment: Going to accept this answer for the work/thought you've put in.  I realize now that the problem was not simply solvable like I thought

Comment: @babonk Cheers.  It is solvable without loops, as demonstrated, but if efficiency is your motive, then you would be best off with the double loop approach, particularly if you do not copy data.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$sets = array();
foreach ($items as $item)
{
    if (!array_key_exists($item['Set_ID'], $sets))
    {
        $sets[$item['Set_ID']] = array();
    }
    $sets[$item['Set_ID']][] = $item;
}
foreach ($sets as $setID => $items)
{
    echo 'Set ' . $setID . ' has ' . count($items) . ' Items: ';
    foreach ($items as $item)
    {
         echo $item['Item_ID'] . ' ' . $item['Item_Name'];
    }
}
?>
```

Something like this i guess?

**EDIT:**
After i posted this i saw the display functions where added. But you get the point.

Comment: has two loops.  want to do it in one

Comment: not posible, or you need to use something like, go next while set id is same, while doing that count. Go back and print count items, and continue. But this asume that the set ids are in order

Comment: From the question: *"However, I'd like to do this all with only one loop."*  Otherwise a fine answer.

Comment: the set ids are in order, so i'm going to try that method.. bout to post my answer

Comment: If the set IDs are in order, you can do it, if you permit a sort first it is then simple.

Answer (score 0):

The need to not print out any items until we know how many there are in the set makes this difficult. At some point, we'll need to doing some buffering, or else backtracking. However, if I'm allowed internal loops, and sets are contiguous in the "master" array, then with some hacking around:

```
$set = 0;
$items;

foreach ($arr as $a) {
    if ($a['Set_ID'] != $set) {
        if ($set != 0) {
            display_set($set, count($items));
            foreach ($items as $i)
                display_item($i)
        }
        $set = $a['Set_ID'];
        $items = array();
    }
    $items[] = $a;
}
```

Comment: is this more efficient than the answer i just posted?  Keep in mind that set_id's are already sorted.  It seems like yours would be less efficient because it has a loop inside a loop and needs to build an array

Comment: @babonk: I don't know, you should benchmark them both if you're genuinely interested. Keep in mind that you're building up a string using repeated concatenation, so don't assume that yours is more efficient just because it has no explicit inner loop. Also keep in mind that memory-wise, keeping the string output like that is likely to consume more memory than building an array.

Comment: @babonk: I agree with Anon. Loops are highly efficient compared to all the string array building.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$previous_set = false;

$items = '';
$item_count = 0;

foreach ($rows as $row)
{
 if ($row['Set_ID'] != $previous_set)
 {
  if ($previous_set)
  {
   echo display_set($row['Set_ID'], $item_count);
   echo $items;
  }
  $previous_class = $row['Set_ID'];
  $item_count = 0;
  $items = '';
 }
 $items .= display_item($row['Item_ID'], $row['Title']);
 $item_count++;

}
echo display_set($row['Set_ID'], $item_count);
echo $items;
```

Comment: My bad.  I see how that makes a huge difference in this problem.  It seems like a one loop solution might be impossible with the other way